# Getting point.x for a location with a bearing near 0

Tags: iphone, geolocation, augmented-reality, bearing

I'm developing my own augmented reality engine.

In this [tutorial](http://www.invasivecode.com/blog/archives/1435) I've found how to display a point on screen using its bearing, iPhone screen size and camera field of view:

```
+ (CGPoint) calculatePositionFor:(float)deltaOrient screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize fov:(float)fov
{
    CGPoint point;

    CGFloat x = (screenSize.width / 2.0f) + (deltaOrient * (screenSize.width / (fov / 2.0f)));
    CGFloat y = screenSize.height / 2.0f;

    point = CGPointMake(x, y);

    return point;
}
```

Its parameters are:

`deltaOrient:` is location's bearing minus device heading.
`screenSize:` iPhone's screen size.
`fov:` camera's field of view.

It works fine until I want show a location near North. When device heading goes from 1 degree to 359 degrees it doesn't work.

I get this log:

```
2011-11-16 15:10:16.067 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 2.504323, X: 234.424377
2011-11-16 15:10:16.104 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 1.504323, X: 250.961853
2011-11-16 15:10:16.117 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 0.504323, X: 267.499329
2011-11-16 15:10:16.149 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 0.504323, X: 267.499329
2011-11-16 15:10:16.172 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 359.504333, X: -5669.451660
2011-11-16 15:10:16.195 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 358.504333, X: -5652.914551
2011-11-16 15:10:16.217 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 358.504333, X: -5652.914551
2011-11-16 15:10:16.244 AREngineDemo[310:707] Beta: 7.005, Heading: 358.504333, X: -5652.914551
```

X coodinate goes from `247` to `-5669`. This is an error.

I'm trying to wonder how to fix it, I don't know how yet.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the calculation of `deltaOrient` is naive. When it goes to 359 from 0, it's probably equal to 359 instead of -1. That's obviously an issue.

I can't think of a good and simple solution to the problem, but you could at least test by doing a hack like this:

```
if(deltaOrient > 180) deltaOrient -= 360;
else if(deltaOrient < -180) deltaOrient += 360;
```